# How do I change my pwd to the real path of a symlinked directory?

Tags: linux, symlink, pwd

Here's a rather elementary *nix question:

Given the following symlink creation:

```
ln -s /usr/local/projects/myproject/ myproject
```

... from my home directory **/home/jvf/**, entering the **myproject** symlink gives me a pwd **/home/jfv/myproject/**. Now, I would like to enter the parent directory of the directory I've symlinked to, but the **cd ..** command will only bring me back to my home directory **/home/jfv/**. Is there anyway to escape the symlink trail that I've entered, and instead have a pwd equal to the actual path of the **myproject** directory. That is, changing my pwd from **/home/jfv/myproject/** into **/usr/local/projects/myproject/**?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Just use `-P` (physical) flag:

```
pwd -P

cd -P ..
```

Answer (score 12):

If you do the following you should be OK.

1) First you follow your symlink:

```
[jfv@localhost ~]$ cd myproject
```

2) Now you execute the following command:

```
[jfv@localhost myproject]$ cd -P ./
```

3) Now, you can check your location and you will see that you are on the physical directory

```
[jfv@localhost myproject]$ pwd
```

The output will be as follows:

```
/usr/local/projects/myproject
```

Now, everything you do will be local and not on the symlink.

Answer (score 3):

Programmatically, you would do this with the getcwd library function:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[1024*1024L];
    char *cwd;

    cwd = getcwd(buf, sizeof buf);
    if (cwd == NULL) {
        perror("getcwd");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%s\n", cwd);
    return 0;
}
```